# Django - filtering on generic related objects

Tags: django, generics, filter

Given the following models adapted from http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/generic_relations/

```
class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    """A tag on an item."""
    tag = models.SlugField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()

class Vegetable(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    is_yucky = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    edible = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Mineral(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    hardness = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    edible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

How would I filter TaggedItems so that I get only those with content_objects that are edible?

ideally, something like:

```
TaggedItem.objects.filter(content_object.edible=True)
```

What if `Vegetable` and `Mineral` had `is_edible` methods?

Comment: Is this django-tagging that you're using?

Comment: No. My actual problem does not involve tags. This was just the first generic relations example I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do this with generic relations, because there's nothing to guarantee that the target model will even have an `edible` field.

An alternative is to change the structure to use model inheritance (multi-table). Vegetable and Mineral would both inherit from a `Taggable` model, which contained the `edible` field (or anything else you need to filter on). Then `TaggedItem` would have a standard `ForeignKey` to `Taggable`, so you would use the standard double-underscore filter syntax.